# Почему не работают условия if и elif?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, sqlite, telebot

Создаю бот с помощью библиотеки Telebot.
Кнопка называется "Писар". Она должена работать когда vip (столбец который в базе данных) равен 250. Это кнопка только для Вип аккаунтов.

Эта кнопка должна работать только когда vip ровно 250, иначе не должеа работать. Вся информация внизу.

У меня вот такой код:
Код из bot.py

```
elif message.text == 'Писар':
            user_info = db.get_gender_chat('male')
            chat_two = user_info[0]
            if db.get_vip(message.chat.id,) == '250':
                if db.create_chat(message.chat.id, chat_two) == False:
                    db.add_queue(message.chat.id, db.get_gender(message.chat.id))
                    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, ' Дар ҳоли ҷустуҷӯ, интизор шавед бо нафаре пайваст мешавед!', reply_markup = stop_search())
                else:
                    mess = 'Нафаре ёфт шуд ки бо шумо дар алоқа аст суҳбатро оғоз намоед \n Барои қатъи сӯҳбат /stop - ро пахш намоед!'

                    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, mess, reply_markup = stop_dialog())
                    bot.send_message(chat_two, mess, reply_markup = stop_dialog())
            else:
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ошибка: Вип не равен 250')
```

Код из database.py:

```
def get_vip(self, vip):
        with self.connection:
            user = self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `vip` = ?", (vip,)).fetchmany(1)
            if bool(len(user)):
                for row in user:
                    return row[3]
            else:
                return False
                
    def get_vip_chat(self, vip):
        with self.connection:
            chat = self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `vip` = ?", (vip,)).fetchmany(1)
            if bool(len(chat)):
                for row in chat:
                    user_info = [row[1], row[3]]
                    return user_info
            else:
                return [0]
```

Таблица из база данных
[image: данные юзери из база данных]

Comment: да у вас попросту опечатка, ненужный пробел в `message.text == ' Писар':`

Comment: помогло? я могу как ответ оформить чтобы вопрос был решённым

Comment: ненужный пробел в строке `' Писар'`

Comment: @PeterKolosov нет, проблема не в этом, в место пробел был смайлик а тут он не появиться

Comment: ааааааааааааааа вот оно что

Comment: а вы попробуйте без смайлика в коде и в телеграме написать

Comment: @PeterKolosov Все ровно не получается. Я думаю проблема в это `if db.get_vip(message.chat.id,) == '250': `  это условие должно считать из база данных столбца vip но не получается

Comment: Попробуйте вызывать не `db.get_vip(message.chat.id,)`, а `db.get_vip(message.from_user.id)`

Comment: И соответственно добавлять в базу не `chat.id`, а `from_user.id`

Comment: @PeterKolosov а как этого сделать? (И соответственно добавлять в базу не chat.id, а from_user.id  )